# Postfix: Optimising order of spam checks?

Tags: postfix, spam

I have a mail server (postfix v3.3) on a VPS running Ubuntu 18.04, processing both inbound and outbound mail (I have some websites sending mail, and some SASL auth users with accounts on the machine) with various systems: rate limiting as well as RBL, DKIM, SPF and virus checking using Amavis and Spamassassin.

However, it's hard to know where to put checks in so they only kick in when other less expensive ones have run while still retaining protection. I'm thinking of configuring main.cf like this, does it look sane? In terms of putting the least expensive checks first, should I be putting more checks in `smtpd_client_restrictions`, for example (since I assume these would run before, say, `smtpd_sender_restrictions`)?

```
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes

smtpd_client_restrictions = 
        check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/blacklist, 
        permit_mynetworks
 
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
        reject_invalid_helo_hostname
 
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        # Filter through Amavis + spamassassin:
        check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/internal_clients_filter,
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =

smtpd_relay_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        # Rate limiting + geolimiting with postfwd
        # See https://github.com/Vnet-as/postfwd-anti-geoip-spam-plugin
        check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10040,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_unlisted_recipient,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        # Sender scoring https://github.com/DavidGoodwin/policyd-dnsbl-spf-geoip/blob/master/README.md 
        check_policy_service unix:private/senderCheck,
        permit_mx_backup

smtpd_data_restrictions =
        reject_unauth_pipelining
```

Answer (score 1):

The tests are fired in the order they are specified in the comma separated list: if a test results in either `permit` or `reject`, all the other tests are omitted. This is how you can omit the more expensive tests if the less expensive are sufficient for the decision. From [Getting selective with SMTP access restriction lists](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#lists):

> Each restriction list is evaluated from left to right until some
> restriction produces a result of PERMIT, REJECT or DEFER (try again
> later). The end of each list is equivalent to a PERMIT result. By
> placing a PERMIT restriction before a REJECT restriction you can make
> exceptions for specific clients or users. This is called allowlisting;
> the fourth example above allows mail from local networks but otherwise
> rejects mail to arbitrary destinations.

This continues with:

> The table below summarizes the purpose of each SMTP access restriction
> list. All lists use the exact same syntax; they differ only in the
> time of evaluation and in the effect of a REJECT or DEFER result.

Therefore, from the perspective of your question it doesn't really matter which SMTP access restriction list you use. However, I'd actually recommend putting most of the tests to the [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) or the [`smtpd_relay_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_relay_restrictions) as both are evaluated after the `RCPT TO` command. This way you'll have the complete `HELO`, `MAIL FROM` and `RCPT TO` preserved in the logs, which might help debugging any false rejections.

Comment: OK good, although I get the impression smtpd_recipient_restrictions is sort of deprecated in favour of smtpd_relay_restrictions (as long as the latter has reject_unlisted_recipient) so as to avoid unexpected permissions. But I'm not sure I understand that properly, since most people do as you say have most of the tests in smtpd_recipient_restrictions.

Comment: I've updated my answer to contain both. The documentation for [`smtpd_relay_before_recipient_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_relay_before_recipient_restrictions) describes this more clearly: "Background: the `smtpd_relay_restrictions` feature is primarily designed to enforce a mail relaying policy, while `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` is primarily designed to enforce spam blocking policy. Both are evaluated while replying to the RCPT TO command, and both support the same features."

Comment: Thanks - another question though: you say tests are fired in the order they are specified in the comma separated list, but is there not an order implied by the restriction "types"? So (for example) the rules in `smtpd_client_restrictions` are evaluated before `smtpd_sender_restrictions` - does that also affect where rules should go?

Comment: Yes, it does: to be precise, the tests are evaluated while replying to the given command (`HELO`, `MAIL FROM` or `RCPT TO`). But that's not the only way to put them in order, as they are also evaluated from left to right and stopped on first match.